# Suspend not working in 16.04 for Dell Inspiron

Tags: suspend

I recently upgraded ubuntu to 16.04 and since then I'm facing the problem of Suspension, computer doesn't wake up after the suspend and only black screen can be seen. What can be the possible solutions for it?

Comment: Please write down the suspension, wake-up, and subsequent shutdown/reboot times and include the entries of `/var/log/syslog` corresponding to that period in your question. Please also include `/var/log/pm-suspend.log`.

Answer (score 0):

Kernel 4.4 is not good. Suspension did not work for me either on 16.04 so I upgraded kernel to 4.5 using these instructions:
http://www.yourownlinux.com/2016/05/how-to-install-linux-kernel-4-5-4-in-linux.html

The problem was solved and I can suspend/hibernate now.